# Add custom column url in generated list.jspx - Spring roo

Tags: java, spring-roo

I created a finder for one of my entities and I would like add a custom URL in a column in my generated list. For example, I would like to create a link like `/custom/idEntity`.  How do I create the link?  Do I have to modify the list.jspx?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit the list.jspx for the entity.

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13273043/1033422) question (and answer) is similar to what you are trying to do.

If you are going to be doing a lot of ROO development, it's worth browsing and understanding the code in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` - there you will find examples of how to do most things you will want to do.

The [spring roo in action](http://www.manning.com/rimple/) book is well worth reading if you are want to become a ROO expert.